# A differential form whose support is in a tubular neighborhood of $T^k\times \{0\}^{n-k}\subset T^n$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, cohomology

Let $\alpha$ be a differential form on the torus $T^n$ whose support $\mathrm{supp}(\alpha)$ is contained in a small neighborhood of the subtorus $T^k\equiv T^k\times \{0\}^{n-k}$.

> **Question:**
> Suppose $\alpha$ is closed or even harmonic with respect to some metric. I was wondering if the de Rham cohomology class $[\alpha]\in H^*_{dR}(T^n)$ has to live in the image of the pullback $H^*_{dR}(T^k)\to H^*_{dR}(T^n)$ induced by the projection $T^n\to T^k$.

Actually I firstly thought about the following question: if $S$ is a singular chain/cycle whose image is contained in a small neighborhood of $T^k$, then do we have $[S]\in H_*(T^n)$ must lie in the image of $H_*(T^k)\to H_*(T^n)$? The answer for this should be positive as we can continuously retract $S$ into $T^k$. But in cohomology theory as above, I get confused.

For simplicity one may assume $k=1$ and $n=2$. For more generality, we may consider a pair of (compact) smooth manifolds $N\subset M$ rather than the torus $T^k\subset T^n$.

Comment: Can't you appeal to Poincare duality? The Poincare dual of $\alpha$ should be a singular chain whose image is contained in a small tubular neighborhood of $T_k$ by definition. Also, the pullback map on de Rham cohomology is the dual of the corresponding map on homology (with real coefficients).

Comment: @RohilPrasad I believe so but cannot persuade myself. I learn from Bott-Tu's book that we can talk about the Poincare dual of a closed oriented submanifold, but in my question I would like to have sort of an inverse process which I have no idea due to my limited knowledge.

Comment: Using the Künneth formula and excision, you can show that $[\alpha]\in H^*_{dR}(T^k)\otimes H^{n-k}(T^{n-k})$. Do you need more details?

Comment: @SebastianGoette Sure, I will appreciate it if you can have more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By compactness, $\operatorname{supp}(\alpha)\subset T^k\times B^{n-k}$,
where $B^{n-k}\subset T^{n-k}$ is a small open ball.
So $[\alpha]$ is in the image of $H^*_{dR}(T^n,T^n\setminus T^k\times B^{n-k})\to H^*_{dR}(T^n)$.
By the Künneth formula and excision,
$$ H^*_{dR}(T^n,T^n\setminus T^k\times B^{n-k})
\cong H^*_{dR}(T^k)\otimes H^*_{dR}(\overline{B^{n-k}},\partial B^{n-k})\;.$$
The second factor only has cohomology in degree $n-k$, generated by, say $[\omega]$. The image of $[\omega]$ in $H^{n-k}(T^{n-k})$ is a generator as well. So there exists a unique $\beta\in H^*_{dR}(T^k)$ such that
$$[\alpha]=[\beta]\otimes[\omega]\;.$$

More generally, let $N\subset M$ both be compact and let $N$ have orientable normal bundle $\nu$. If $U\subset M$ is a tubular neighbourhood of $N$ with $\operatorname{supp}(\alpha)\subset U$, then $U$ is diffeomorphic to $\nu$ and $[\alpha]$ is in the image of
$$H^*_{dR}(N)\stackrel\Theta\longrightarrow H^*_{dR}(M,M\setminus U)\longrightarrow H^*_{dR}(M)\;,$$
where $\Theta$ is the Thom isomorphism for the normal bundle (followed by excision).
This composition is sometimes denoted $\iota_!$ ($\iota\colon N\to M$ is the inclusion). It raises degree by the rank of the normal bundle.

If both $N$ and $M$ are oriented, then so is $\nu$, and one can describe $\iota_!$ by conjugating the push forward $\iota_*$ in homology with Poincaré duality on $N$ and $M$.

Comment: If $N$ is a codim-1 separating submanifold in $M$, I think any element in the image of the Mayer-Vietoris map $H^k(N)\to H^{k+1}(M)$ has support in a small neighborhood of $N$ (referring to a representative of the element). So is there a relation between this MV map and the shriek $\iota_!$? (I imagine this is standard.)